# Compare file permissions from different folders

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

I have this code that checks an entire directory for files permissions.
The problem is that they are a lot and keep adding up.

```
output message "CHECKING FOR FILES PERMISSION"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATHDEST -Recurse | % { $_.isreadonly = $true }
$attribute = [io.fileattributes]::ReadOnly
Foreach($file in $files) {
   if((Get-ItemProperty -Path $PATHDEST"\"$file).attributes -band $attribute){
       attrib -r $PATHDEST"\"$file /s
   }
}
```

This is used when deploying a new version of the application just to make sure no problems occur in the deploy.

Now, what I really wanted is to check the permission of the files that are going to be updated and not the entire directory ...

Comment: This is not clear. Are you trying to remove the readonly permission on files where it is set? Or trying to set all files in a directory to be readonly?

Comment: +1 for question not clear. If you want only "files that are going to be updated and not the entire directory" you should add the `-File` flag to `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: I want to check if the files have readonly and if yes, remove it. Now I'm checking the all directory, but I want to check only the files that going to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you should probably be able to do this like this:

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $PATHDEST -Recurse -File)) { 
    if ($file.IsReadOnly) {
        $file.IsReadOnly = $false
    }
}
```

This would iterate over all the Files in `$PATHDEST` (not folders) recursively and will remove the Read-Only attribute from Read-Only files.

It is better to use `$file.IsReadOnly = $false` then `attrib` since it doesn't uses external tool to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all readonly files and remove the readonly permission, you can use the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $PATHDEST -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.isreadonly -eq $true } | Foreach-Object { attrib -r $_ }
```

This will use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter all the readonly files, then pass them down the pipeline to the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet that will take an action on the filtered list, running the `attrib -r` command on the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% what the exact issue is but I understand it as >

- performance
- & the fact that the code you have written is executed once. However, new files are coming in and this needs to be caught.

Let me suggest the following.

## **Performance**

1. Use the -filter parameter on the get-childitem cmdlet. Whenever a -filter parameter is available on a PowerShell cmdlet the objects that are retrieved by the cmdlet are processed in a more performant way.
2. Use the -file parameter on the Get-childitem to get only files.

## **Regarding files that keep coming in**

1. Now, as you don't mention what the application you are trying to deploy is I might be missing some domain details. But. If I was you I would try to dive into:

   - Seeing if the application can provide you with a list over the files that are going to be updated. Likely the applications has to know this.
   - Isn't it possible to query for updated files after the application has been deployed? If so, do that and react after the app. has been deployed. If the case is that you continously have to monitor the folder for changed files I would look into using the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher ... here is a good example > https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx

I hope this helps. Have a great day.